# How can i fire DOM-api methods like .click() in componentDidMount() with laravel-mix

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-mix

I would like to fire onClick function when react component mounts (renders). I like to use javascript DOM API method .click(). It works fine in react application (without laravel-mix) and off-course in console.

What should i have to do to get same functionality in laravel-react app with laravel-mix???

Expected Output: alert box with clicked message

Actual Output: nothing

```
//to fire onClick     
document.getElementById("imgInput").click()

//used in pure componentDidMount
 componentDidMount = () => {
    document.getElementById("imgInput").click();
};

//code on fire
_handleClick =()=>{
  alert('clicked');
}
```

```
 <button id="imgInput" onClick={this.handleClick} type="file">
        click me
 </button> 

//Edited with react ref

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.imgInputRef = React.createRef();

  }

  componentDidMount = () => {

    if ( this.imgInputRef) {
      const $ref = this.imgInputRef;
      $ref.current.click();
    }

  };



  _onUploadImageHandler =  e => {
    // handeling image upload 
  };

  //rendering button
  <div>
    <input
      accept="image/*"
      type="file"
      multiple
      id="imgInput"
      ref={this.imgInputRef}

      onChange={this._onUploadImageHandler}
    />
    <label htmlFor="imgInput" style={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <Button
        htmlFor="imgInput"
        variant="contained"
        component="span"
        size="large"
        style={{ width: "100%" }}

      >
        <CloudUpload />
        <span>{uploadBtnText}</span>
      </Button>
    </label>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). It will have reference of underlying html input and use its functions. Using `ref` instead of `document.getElementById("imgInput")` is a good approach

In your render method:

```
<input ref={input => this.inputElement = input} ... />
```

New way for creating `ref` is

```
// In constructor
this.myRef = React.createRef();
// in render method
<input ref={this.myRef} />
```

In your event handler:

```
this.inputElement.click();
```

Comment: Appreciate, i have already tried with refs as well , actually this.myRef.current.click() must work and is working in other applications as well (pure react app). Is there anything we have allow in webpack.mix.js file ??

Comment: No ref doesn't have anything to do the `webpack.config.js`. Please accept answer if your question answered

Comment: still not getting solution for it, it doesn't show any errors as well

Comment: Have you tried ‘this.myRef.click()’. It should work.please also see ref documentation link attached in the answer

Comment: I have tried that as well, will you please check the code edited on post so that you can find my mistakes and suggest me further

Comment: No Its not confusing, I just want to verify changes. I think using `$ref.click()` instead of `$ref.current.click()` would work. Other suggestion is why you are stimulation click why not just execute function in `componentDidMount`. If these suggestions work, not need for codesandbox.